# Display buttons side by side | Unobtrusive method?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make have two buttons side by side, as in the screenshot below.

I have tried numerous resources online but to no luck. I have even tried making the broader column into a row, however, that throws off the design completely.

Is there a way to add a second button beside the current one without being too obtrusive?

```
  const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            OutlineButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Continue'),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff33333D)),
```

Which is apart of

```
Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Some Text',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Text(
                  "Some Text.",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Continue'),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff33333D)),
```

Edit based on answer:

```
Row(
                    children: [
                      OutlineButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Login'),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Color(0xff33333D),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                        height: 25,
                      ),
                      OutlineButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Sign Up'),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Color(0xff33333D),
```

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it with parent Row widget

```
  Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(""),
      Text(""),
      Row(
        children: [
          OutlineButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Continue'),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xff33333D),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          OutlineButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Continue'),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xff33333D),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  )
```

Comment: This works, but do you know why I have lost the spacing between my buttons, and the above text? Right now they are pushed too high and are right against the text, but nothing appears to have really changed. I have added the change to the original post

Comment: Nevermind, realized I was missing a const sizebox. Thanks for the help!